# Catch block does not catch errors

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code and when I manipulate the try block so that there occur errors the catch block does not catch them (for example errors that the Facebook SDK throws). I am really new to using the try and catch structure and do not understand how I can handle the facebook errors.

```
try{

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.7'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

    };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = $fbSource;  
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

}catch(e){

    console.log('Error: '+e);

}
```

Comment: Show us exactly where you're causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: The `catch` block only catches thrown errors, not facebook errors?

Comment: It is not going to catch asynchronous issues

Answer (score 2):

That's because the errors aren't being thrown when the `try` block is active. By the time the errors are being thrown (later, when Facebook calls your `fbAsyncInit` function), the code has long since exited the `try` block.

If you want to catch those errors, you'll need a `try` block *within* your `fbAsyncInit` callback and/or to receive errors in the way the FB API indicates, since most async APIs can't (by nature) be compatible with `try/catch`.

Comment: @JuliusS.: With any vaguely-modern browser you can use an `onerror` callback on the [`script` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) you're using to load Facebook, perhaps also with an `onload` and a timeout if you don't see either within a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: @JuliusS: The comment I was relying to seems to have been deleted, but hopefully the above is useful.